# In Field Service Lightning Test Class on ServiceReport throws Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

In Field Service Lightning I have a Trigger on ServiceReport which sends an email with attachment coming from ContentVersion.

This is the Test class I have written.

```
@isTest

private class testCreateServiceReport{

     static testMethod void validateWO() {

     WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder();

     wo.subject = 'Testing';

     insert wo;

     ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment();

     sa.ParentRecordId = wo.Id;

     sa.EarliestStartTime = DateTime.now();

     sa.DueDate = DateTime.now();

     insert sa;

     List<ServiceReportLayout> srl = [Select Id FROM ServiceReportLayout];

     ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();

     sr.ParentId = sa.Id;

     sr.Template = srl[0].Id; //Need to check if there is a way to avoid srl[0] notation

     insert sr; //If I comment this the text result is pass. When I enable it I get too see the below mentioned error.

}

}
```

This is the error `Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts` I know that we need to write Test Classes for code that involves web service callouts using setMock() but I dont understand in what way inserting ServiceReport is related to making a callout.

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my theory.

From Salesforce docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_customer_reports_settings.htm&type=5):

> A service report is a PDF that summarizes a work order or service
>   appointment and can be signed by customers and your team members. To
>   control what shows up in your service reports, create service report
>   templates.

So basically insertion of `ServiceReport` creates a PDF.

The way salesforce creates a pdf is via calling `getContentAsPDF` method.

Now from [Winter 17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_vf_cruc.htm), `getContentAsPDF` is treated as callout. As its a callout in test context one needs a mock.

The funny part is you cannot call `getContentAsPDF` in test context as mentioned [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HzknAAC). So on top of my head, you wont be able to test insertion of `ServiceReport`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do this with help of this post:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g9k2QAA

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'testAccountSA',
                        BillingPostalCode = '83059',
                        BillingCountry = 'Deutschland');
    insert a; 

    Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'TESTOS',
                       LastName = 'TEstmann',
                       AccountId = a.id);
    insert c;

    Case cas = new Case (AccountId = a.Id,
                        STATUS = 'New',
                        Origin = 'Homepage',
                        created_by__c = 'bla');
        insert cas;

    WorkOrder WO = new WorkOrder (AccountId = a.Id,
                                 CaseId = cas.Id);
        insert WO;

    ServiceAppointment SA = new ServiceAppointment (Case__c = cas.Id,
                                                    ParentRecordId = WO.Id);
        insert SA;ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(


Title = 'Penguins',
  PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
  VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
  IsMajorVersion = true
);
insert contentVersion;    
List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

//create ContentDocumentLink  record 
ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.LinkedEntityId = WO.id;
cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
cdl.shareType = 'V';
insert cdl;


ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();
sr.ContentVersionDocumentId = documents[0].Id ;
sr.DocumentBody = Blob.valueOf('Test Content') ; 
sr.DocumentContentType ='application/pdf';
sr.DocumentName='Test';
sr.ParentId = WO.Id ; 
insert sr ;
```